# Show/Hide fields without record types - Lightning

Tags: lightning, page-layout

We are planning to use record types for the Lead object. For one of these record types we have a layout with several custom fields which show / hide depending on eachothers value. Sample 2 fields:

1. HasOwnDistributor__c (Boolean)
2. DistributorName__c (String)

As you can imagine, the distributor name (2) does not have to be visible if the boolean is set to false (1).

Since we are already using record types, different layouts is not an option anymore. Which options do we have?

We are using the Lightning Experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible today to do with any standard layout.

You have 3 options:

1. Develop your own layout with VisualForce pages or lightning components (really not recommended, but a viable option).
2. See this idea: [Dependent page layouts](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BroxAAC) and wait until it will be GA.
3. See this article: [Dependent Page Layouts – Dynamically Hide/Show Form Fields in Lightning Experience](https://douglascayers.com/2017/06/24/dependent-page-layouts-dynamically-hideshow-form-fields-in-lightning-experience/) and try to use flows in your lightning layouts.